# Why my wordpress website speed is very slowly after installation by docker? How to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, docker

i'm installed wordpress in VPS by docker using this instruction: https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/install-wordpress-with-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04/ Additionally I add only domain forwading to VPS DNS (and this is works). But I didn't add more there - only these instructions and DNS change I did.

The VPS has 16 GB RAM, 6 vCPU Cores, 400 GB SSD and Ubuntu 20.04 as the installed OS.

But execution server time (looking up on HTTP request in PageSpeed Insights) is very bad, because is between 600 and 2000 milliseconds (only server reaction time, not total loading time). If you are looking on used by me instructions (from linked website), what do you think what will be the solution in this situation?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: "600 and 2000 microseconds" sounds terrific. Other people would do anything to get into that range

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes but only if it will be total loading time, but this is only server execution (backend) index...

Comment: 600 microseconds, thats 0.6 milliseconds - how did you even measure that?

Comment: You're right, i wrote with wrong prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a pluggin in your wordpress site for cache, example: *WP Fastest Cache*...

There are alot of pluggins for cache. Click on link below to see more solutions.

https://blog.hubspot.com/website/best-wordpress-cache-plugins-to-speed-up-a-site

Hope that I've answared your question, if not feel free to ask me again. Bye